# How to cast TResult which can be an object or List<object> inside an Expression<Func<T,TResult?>?

Tags: c#, .net, generics, .net-core, .net-6.0

As the title says, "How to cast `TResult` which can be an `object` or `List<object>` inside an `Expression<Func<T,TResult?>`?"

```
    public Task ExplicitLoadAsync<TProperty>(T entity, Expression<Func<T, TProperty?>> propertyExpression) where TProperty : class
    {
        var typeOfProp = typeof(TProperty);
        if (typeOfProp.IsInterface && typeOfProp.GetGenericTypeDefinition() == typeof(ICollection<>))
        {
            var collectionExpression = propertyExpression as Expression<Func<T, IEnumerable<TProperty>>>;
            if (collectionExpression is not null)
            {
                return _dbContext.Entry(entity).Collection(collectionExpression).LoadAsync();
            }
        }

        return _dbContext.Entry(entity).Reference(propertyExpression).LoadAsync();
    }
```

`collectionExpression` will always be null, the issue is that `Reference()` only accept `IEnumerable<TProperty>` and overload is not possible because it will always use the method with `TProperty` instead of `Expression<Func<T, IEnumerable<TProperty>>> propertyExpression`

The reason is the cast is wrong because it will be `IEnumerable<IEnumerable<...>>` How to solve it?

One way is to have two methods with different names, but I would like to skip that as that would require more refactoring in the whole code base.

Comment: If `TProperty` can be an `object` or a `List<object>`, why don't you check which one it is first before performing your cast?  `if (TProperty.GetGenericTypeDefinition() == typeof(IEnumerable<>))`

Comment: I am already doing it with typeof(ICollection<>),
The issue is pass it down to the `Collection` method

TProperty is already "list" but the method is not aware of it.

Comment: maybe it not possible to solve? I will use propertyPathName instead and use a utility to generate the pathName from the expression.

Comment: There's something I don't quite understand here.  You're passing in an `Expression<Func<T, TProperty?>>` but you're expecting it to be an `Expression<Func<T, IEnumerable<TProperty>>`.  Why not just pass in an `Expression<Func<T, IEnumerable<TProperty>>`?

Comment: The big issue is that overload won't work because TProperty could be anything so it will always pick the most generic overload and the cast is wrong in my code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This solution is based on [Guru Stron's deleted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73985195/13268855)

```
public async Task ExplicitLoadAsync<T, TProperty>(T entity, Expression<Func<T, IEnumerable<TProperty>>> propertiesExpression) where T : class where TProperty : class
  => await _dbContext.Entry(entity).Collection(propertiesExpression).LoadAsync();

public async Task ExplicitLoadAsync<T, TProperty>(T entity, Expression<Func<T, TProperty?>> propertyExpression) where T : class where TProperty : class
 => await _dbContext.Entry(entity).Reference(propertyExpression).LoadAsync();
```

Here the trick is to use different parameter names:

- `Expression<Func<T, IEnumerable<TProperty>>> propertiesExpression`
- `Expression<Func<T, TProperty?>> propertyExpression`

which allows you to be able to call both overloads

```
ExplicitLoadAsync<Entity, string>(enity, e => e.SingleString);
ExplicitLoadAsync<Entity, string>(enity, propertiesExpression: e => e.CollectionOfStrings);
```

Comment: Ah thank you, I forgot about that. :D  That will work but I will then have to explicit call the parameter name.

Comment: @XzaR Yes, this makes the solution sub-optimal, but I'm unaware of any other technique to enforce explicit overload call if there is an accept-anything overload as well. Either you push that burden on the caller side or as you did you do it inside the method itself.

Answer (score 1):

I just want to post another answer to solve my case without calling the method with parameter name from the answer of Peter Csala.

```
public Task ExplicitLoadAsync<TProperty>(T entity, Expression<Func<T, TProperty?>> propertyExpression) where TProperty : class
{
    var typeOfProp = typeof(TProperty);
    if (typeOfProp.IsInterface && typeOfProp.GetGenericTypeDefinition() == typeof(ICollection<>))
    {
         var pathName = PropertyPath<T>.GetAsStr(propertyExpression);
         return _dbContext.Entry(entity).Collection(pathName).LoadAsync();
    }

    return _dbContext.Entry(entity).Reference(propertyExpression).LoadAsync();
}
```

Here is the utility class:

```
public static class PropertyPath<TSource>
{
    public static IReadOnlyList<MemberInfo> Get<TResult>(Expression<Func<TSource, TResult>> expression)
    {
        var visitor = new PropertyVisitor();
        visitor.Visit(expression.Body);
        visitor._path.Reverse();
        return visitor._path;
    }

    public static string GetAsStr<TResult>(Expression<Func<TSource, TResult>> expression)
    {
        return string.Join(".", Get(expression).Select(p => p.Name));
    }

    private sealed class PropertyVisitor : ExpressionVisitor
    {
        internal readonly List<MemberInfo> _path = new();

        protected override Expression VisitMember(MemberExpression node)
        {
            if (node.Member is not PropertyInfo)
            {
                throw new ArgumentException("The path can only contain properties", nameof(node));
            }

            _path.Add(node.Member);
            return base.VisitMember(node);
        }
    }
}
```